# What does "looser schema definition" mean when speaking about the differences between NoSQL and RDBMS?

Tags: nosql

I would like to know what the term "looser schema definition" means speaking about how does NoSQL vary from RDBMS. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

The typcial RDBMS will have a rigid predefined schema that is used for both writing and reading data.

In many cases for NoSQL there will be a `schema on read` that is applied only when *reading* the data. In fact different `schema`s may be used by different applications for the *same* data: they will then have different "views" of the data.

Here is an introduction to the topic:  http://www.marklogic.com/blog/schema-on-read-vs-schema-on-write/

Note this introduces some risk: the application may fail at runtime if the data were not in the format expected.

Comment: @Jacek  Maybe you can provide some more detail in your original question about what you were looking for.